# OpenCV contrib alphamat

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, vcpkg

I want to play around with alphamat, so I installed OpenCV with additional modules like this:

`vcpkg install opencv[contrib]:x64-windows`

It installed all additional modules except alphamat, even though it's supposed to be included. Then I found out that Eigen is needed for alphamat, so I installed it as well. However, when I tried to reinstall, alphamat still didn't get installed.

Next, I attempted to install alphamat separately like this:

`vcpkg install opencv[alphamat]:x64-windows`
But it gave me this message: "opencv has no feature named alphamat. Note: updating vcpkg by rerunning bootstrap-vcpkg may resolve this failure."

However, when I install extra modules like DNN separately, for example:
`vcpkg install opencv[dnn]:x64-windows`
Everything works fine.

I've tried updating everything and retrying, but I'm still getting no results. I would appreciate any ideas. I'm using vcpkg for package management.

Comment: vcpkg surely has a packaga maintainer for that stuff, right? that's the one to talk to. -- by the way, I think alphamat is from the contrib modules, not the main modules